# Search and replace selectively across whole project in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I need to change occurrences of a term only in certain places in my project.

Is there a way in Sublime Text to navigate the search results (across an entire project) and **only** replace the **occurrences of my choice**?

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> opens the "search and replace" for the entire project, but the `Replace` button only gives me the option to replace all occurrences.

Comment: Any updates on this one? I have the exact same requirement now. I need to do a project wide search and have to choose to just click 1 button to replace the matching occurrence or not. I guess we can have some dialogue sort of thing popup for these occurrences asking to decide for each match.

Answer (score 1):

If you press the <kbd>...</kbd> button in the search panel, a menu will open that allows you to refine your search. You can use the `Where` input field with a search pattern, or some tags like `<open-files>`.

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html

Other than that, if you really need human input to decide where to replace and where not to replace, you can go to the next result by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and pasting the code manually.

Just in case you didn't know: when you make a project search a new text file opens up with all the occurrences. You can click those occurrences to navigate to the file in question.

Comment: Thanks, @Pier! I've been using most of those. The functionality I described exists for searching in one file (Cmd + Option + F opens it). I wanted to know if it exists for project-wide searches, but it probably hasn't been implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, the functionality to search/find and replace inside the open project does exist. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and add `<open project>` to the `Where` input field.